# More user-friendly behaviour for too-long titles in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, usability

Using a title longer than 100 characters for a Data Explorer query produces an MS SQL error message:

```
String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.
```

This should be made more user-friendly by checking the title length before passing it to the database and displaying a more appropriate error message:

```
Query title may not exceed 100 characters.
```

Also consider setting `maxlength="100"` on the title `<input>`.

Comment: +1 but if you feel like it you [could make the change yourself](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/)

Comment: @ConradFrix I considered and took a look at the code before posting this, but I don't think I'd get it correct without a Windows setup to test it in. :P

Comment: yeah that's a problem with open source projects that use the MS stack :(

Comment: I'd give an extra upvote for determining the cause of the error if I could.  Excellent bug report.

Comment: You're looking for `~/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/Query/Editor.cshtml`, line 26 per the latest rev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought that was being checked for, but it seems not. Good catch.

I've [pushed a fix](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=d2407b2e34083041b3a07638cc9d76228e86f8cb) for both the `maxlength="100"` and server-side checking for the title and description (and then [another](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=571a407e856390ba3d51ddaf738fd6dddfa748ee) since I wasn't paying attention and used poor word choice in the original error messages).

[Obligatory stock comment about asking waffles to pull changes soon so it can be deployed.]